# Firebase functions project - Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source

Tags: firebase, openapi, twilio-api

I am trying to create a whatsapp/openai chat "app" using Twilio and Firebase functions. I am working off this guy's project [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtzuhxyrAgM&list=PLje69HBrcyJSvA76fRVghuvk814zQOW7X&index=5)

When I try to deploy the project to firebase functions I get the below error.

> Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead

This is the code I am trying to deploy:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

import {
  Configuration,
  OpenAIApi
  } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
  });

const openAI = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
    var messageResponse = new MessagingResponse();
    const sentMessage = req.body.Body || '';
    
    let replyToBeSent = "";
    
    if (sentMessage.trim().length === 0) {
        replyToBeSent = "We could not get your message. Please try again";
    } else {
        try {
            const completion = await openAI.createCompletion({
                model: "text-davinci-003", // required
                prompt: req.body.Body, // completion based on this
                temperature: 0.6, //
                n: 1,
                max_tokens: 50,
                // stop: "."
            });
        
            replyToBeSent = removeIncompleteText(completion.data.choices[0].text)

        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                replyToBeSent = "There was an issue with the server"
            } else { // error getting response
                replyToBeSent = "An error occurred during your request.";
            }
        }
    }

    messageResponse.message(replyToBeSent);
    // send response
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
    });
    res.end(messageResponse.toString());
}

 //trims out the words/char that may be left hanging by chatgpt because the character(token) limit is reached for a response
function removeIncompleteText(inputString) {
    const match = inputString.match(/\b\.\s\d+/g);
    const removeAfter = match ? inputString.slice(0, inputString.lastIndexOf(match[match.length - 1])) : inputString;
    return removeAfter
    }
```

This is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "appName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
     "lint": "eslint .",
     "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
     "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
     "start": "npm run shell",
     "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
     "logs": "firebase functions:log",
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.0",
    "next": "^13.2.4",
    "openai": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "twilio": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0"
  },
 "private": true,
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC"
}
```

When i remove the "type": "module" from the package json file I get the below error.

> Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I am not sure what cannot import statement outside a module means, but i have moved the openAi module file to node_modules folder and I still get the error.

Comment: i changed the: const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
  }); to const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai'); .....and also changed the export default async function ......to exports.handler = async (req, res) => {....... the code deploys to firebase functions, but the problem is when i check firebase functions it does not appear. bear with me a newbie here

Answer (score 1):

i changed:

```
import {Configuration, OpenAIApi} from "openai";
```

changed to

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');
```

.....and also changed

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
```

to this line

```
exports.messages = functions.https.onRequest( async (req, res) => {
```